# "Error getting audio" in audio record using Recorder.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio-recording, recorder.js

I am using this example [Recorder.js Demo](https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html) for recording audios. It's working fine in Linux, but when I use it on Windows. It gives the alert "Error getting audio", For this code is as below

```
function initAudio() {
        //Some code

    navigator.getUserMedia(
        {
            "audio": {
                "mandatory": {
                    "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                    "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                    "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                    "googHighpassFilter": "false"
                },
                "optional": []
            },
        }, gotStream, function(e) {
            console.log("In gotStream function :" +e);
            alert('Error getting audio');
            console.log(e);
        });
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. The problem is that Chrome has recently changed to require secure origins for all powerful APIs, in particular getUserMedia. I have to run this on https://host not on http://host, otherwise getUserMedia will be failed.

Comment: If needed, you can whitelist domains in Chrome's advanced settings if you're just testing at the moment.